# Redirecting to a different login page on devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I searched around and I found out that using
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
on the controller would make it required for the user to be logged in to see that view, but if the user is not logged in and I try to access a page that requires login, it redirects me to /user/sign_in. Can I change this default behavior? I wanted to redirect to a page I created with a login form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change where it redirects to by adding this to your routes.rb file:

```
devise_scope :user do
  get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

See the [Devise wiki for more info](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes)

Comment: I love lightning-fast answers.

Comment: This actually didn't fully solve my problem, but with this I went in the right direction and actually found out how to solve it. Thanks!
What I actually did was to add :skip => [:sessions], then do all the sessions redirects manually.